# How to install gulp jshint using npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, jshint

Unable to install JSHint. Can anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong?

I am using below command.

`npm install --save-dev gulp-jshint gulp-jscs jshint-stylish`

It is showing the following "gulp-jshint@2.0.4 requires a peer of jshint@2.x but none was installed-UNMET peer dependency"

Comment: is `jshint` installed?

Comment: Since v2.0, `jshint` must be installed with `gulp-jshint`.

Comment: Ok so I need  to install jshint before running this command. But now I am getting an error while executing "gulp style" command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try executing the following command `npm install --save-dev jshint gulp-jshint gulp-jscs jshint-stylish`

Comment: Thanks. But Now I am getting error while executing command "gulp style"

Answer (score 1):

peer dependency is not installed by npm you must install it manually before.
In your case :

```
npm install --save-dev jshint
```

**Update**

Peer dependency is a dependency for a library that is not required. It is considered as a plugin.

You can find more informations [here for npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies) or [here for nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/)

Comment: Your command runs perfectly and it done my work but C.an you explain in detail that What is peer dependency here. It may look like silly question but I am new to Node.js and just exploring it. Now I am getting error while executing command "gulp style".